# Como hacer para que el programa me diga que numero es el que mas se repite en una matriz llenada por el usuario

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/* run this program using the console pauser or add your own getch, system("pause") or input loop */

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    int arreglo[10][10], i, j, suma, promedio,filas, columnas;

    printf("Ingrese la cantidad de filas(MAX.10):");

    scanf("%d",&filas);

    printf("Ingrese la cantidad de columnas(MAX.10):");

    scanf("%d",&columnas);

    for(i=0;i<filas;i++){

        for(j=0;j<columnas;j++){

            printf("Ingrese un numero:");

            scanf("%d",&arreglo[i][j]);

            suma+=arreglo[i][j];

        }

    }

    for(i=0;i<filas;i++){

            for(j=0;j<columnas;j++){

                printf("%d",arreglo[i][j]);

            }

            printf("\n");

        }

    printf("La suma de los numeros es:%d \n",suma);

    printf("El promedio de los numeros es: %d \n",suma/=filas*columnas);

    return 0;

}
```

Este es el codigo, el lenguaje es C

Answer (score 0):

El mínimo de repeticiones es 1 y el máximo filas × columnas por lo que si quieres un recuento de todos los números necesitarás una formación de como mínimo filas × columnas elementos ¿qué elementos? pues un objeto que contenga el número y su recuento:

```
typedef struct recuento
{
    int numero;
    int apariciones;
} recuento;

recuento numeros[100];
```

Acto seguido, puedes crear una función que acumule los recuentos:

```
int cuenta(int valor, recuento *numeros, int tamanyo)
{
    for (int i = 0; i != tamanyo; ++i)
    {
        if (numeros[i].numero == valor)
        {
            ++numeros[i].apariciones;
            return tamanyo;
        }
    }

    numeros[tamanyo].numero = valor;
    numeros[tamanyo].apariciones = 1;
    return tamanyo + 1;
}
```

Puedes usarlo así:

```
int contados = 0;

for(int i = 0; i < filas; ++i) {
        for(int j = 0; j < columnas; ++j) {
        printf("Ingrese un numero:");
        scanf("%d", &arreglo[i][j]);
        contados = cuenta(arreglo[i][j], numeros, contados);
        }
}
```

Al acabar de rellenar los datos, en `numeros` tendrás que buscar cuál es el objeto `recuento` con un valor mayor en `apariciones`.

Puedes ver el código funcionando en <kbd>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jZNNj5swEIbP@FdMU@0KCo2guZVNpR576L1SysG1TeqI2JFtIq2q/PZ08AcL2q1UDMJ4Hr8evTOwj2yg6ni/v5eKDSMX8GQdl3r7@wtZLQ3y17RG3PNFcNGDdWZkDoxgo1BOkz8kk8qBGs/C6DZ80As1kkmthG3JbWZbQqao/6D5NL3SQZtqBuBDkLEVTFFHz1Q962I6o9cG/BYJe6hbfL3bJ6CFspQFyRDLZA95FDnIbhumsN@HoxDyVFaWC2iVLgaNcKNRszou3QjeJEt7YuRFPqi3bxALbcQaRNbqUE6Lt@DMmUqVX7XkRbKVGiOOgz40dTc9VS8Hiu4wPYxnRa2Xi96lo5u67tDp7GJQoM8339TRCCtgoMCocpJTDlhbr5R///pj29TF502BUhbjuOGBb6pHHy7@Qyel8m@pRHg13wAa68@19ZUkvrbr0j6F7EJdAa2AeCXyFMgTkrMVCJ88nL1KeVTRnZBctkwPHpPHsjucuhBfZBi7dQVVMPdpIqd9KcvYLW@2bOJTz865PnD/2wgmAKdXfNufajOf9NLMq6Xlr@b9jd2Fvt7u9x3ZkQbHJz92cfwF)</kbd>.